# tf.where() on broadcast arrays

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

I have two arrays (x is 1D and y is 2D). I have calculated the array "diff" which is basically the broadcast difference (x-y[:,None]). I would like to replace all zeroes in the array "diff" with a large value (say 10000). This operation is trivial in numpy as you see below:

```
x=np.array([1.0,1.0,1.0])
y=np.array([[1.0,1.0,1.0],[0.0,0.0,0.0]])
diff = x - y[:, None]
diff = np.where(diff==0.0,10000,diff)
```

However, I am not able to reproduce the same behavior in Tensorflow. I tried the following code block.

```
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32) 
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
diff = x - y[:,None]
diff_zero = tf.cast(tf.zeros_like(diff),tf.float32)
diff_big = tf.cast(tf.ones_like(diff)*100000,tf.float32)

diff = tf.where(diff==diff_zero, diff_big, diff)

sess = tf.Session()
diff_array = sess.run(diff, feed_dict={x: [1.0,1.0,1.0], y: [[1.0,1.0,1.0],[0.0,0.0,0.0]]})
```

Any work-around would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to do it. I had to use tf.equal() instead of "==". The following lines of code did the job just like numpy.

```
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32) 
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
diff = x - y[:,None]

diff_zero = tf.cast(tf.zeros_like(diff),tf.float32)
diff_big = tf.cast(tf.ones_like(diff)*100000,tf.float32)

condition = tf.equal(diff_zero, diff)
diff = tf.where(condition, diff_big, diff)
sess = tf.Session()

diff_array = sess.run(diff, feed_dict={x: [1.0,1.0,1.0], y: [[1.0,1.0,1.0],[0.0,0.0,0.0]]})
```